# TIKA Server extract embedded resources

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

I'm making some tests with the `TIKA`-app (v `1.23`) to extract embedded resources from the input-file, which works great by specifying the `-z` parameter on the command-line using the `app`. This parameter enables embedded resource extraction and writes the resources to the working directory. Now, I would like to use this functionality, based on the `TIKA`-server. However, I haven't been able to find the correct way to do so in the documentation and I wonder or the server-variant of `TIKA` provides this option?

So, how can I extract embedded resources using the `TIKA`-**server** application? *Please note, I'm not looking for the content of the embedded resources, but for the actual binary file data (I want to separate the attachments from the input file)*

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar function available through Apache Tika Server's */unpack* endpoint. If you combine this with the *X-Tika-PDFExtractInlineImages* header set to true, it does the equivalent processing.

For example:

```
curl -T test.pdf http://localhost:9998/unpack > test.zip --header "X-Tika-PDFExtractInlineImages: true"
```

Will return a ZIP file with all the images within the ZIP.

You can read more about the endpoint [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-UnpackResource).

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can see a list of the available header options?

Comment: There isn't a definitive list, we could probably build something to generate them. This answer gives the route to finding them all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011038/apache-tika-server-request-header-parameters

Comment: I did manage to track down that thread after posting. It got me what I needed. I definitely would have benefitted from that information being available on the confluence page. If not a full list, then at least links to the OCR and PDF api's and instructions for renaming them for use with Tika-server.